# Error creating Symfony2 project from composer

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I try to create a Symfony2 project with composer on Ubuntu with command:

```
php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition projectpath
```

And I get this error

```
Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (dev-master 506ffaab8d8474db2512fca879ca4b9877616a1e)
  - Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (dev-master master)
    Cloning master

Created project in projectpath/
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Your lock file is out of sync with your composer.json, run "composer.phar update" to update dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony == 2.1.9999999.9999999-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev.
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony dev-master, symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev.
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony == 9999999-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony dev-master.
```

composer.phar update also return an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to remove your composer.lock file.

Comment: Have you tried doing what it says? Namely: `php composer.phar update` before installing?

Comment: yes, it also return an error :Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/monolog-bundle v2.1.0-BETA1 requires symfony/config 2.1.* -> satisfiable...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try by specifying the exact version you want, it has now been fixed in the symfony-standard repo and this should work:

```
 php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition projectpath 2.1.x-dev
```